# Install on Wordpress ends in 404 via HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, error, installation, ssl

I have a testing site I wish to install civiCRM on. The server and software specs all match [civiCRM's requirements as seen here](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+WordPress). The pre-install check all seems to be okay with it's green text.

After waiting a minute or so for the install to finish it results in a 404 error. I made brand new WordPress installs, databases, etc. but I still get the same 'page not found.'

*Except* when I don't force https when installing WordPress. Upon two clean installs, I've gotten Civi installed.

Some things I noted,

- Disabling all plugins doesn't appear to impact the issue.
- Installing civiCRM with a separate database (with HTTPS) gives me the Green Install notification, *but* trying to click on the civiCRM link in the menu resulted in a 500 error. Further, removing civi and trying to start again gave me 500s even on the pre-install page, I suspect something went wrong with using a new databse I created for civi.

Any Suggestions on how to troubleshoot this and get the install working?

Comment: You'll need to post what the 500 error was for anyone to be able to help you.